# Runtime error '9' Subscript out of range on passing in sheet's codename

Tags: vba, excel

I am running into a subscript out of range error and I don't know what that means. The error specifically occurs at a sub called RedBorder that is called within a sub called validateDropDown, validateDropDown is in a module called validationTools, so is RedBorder. validateDropDown is called in ValidateSheet and ValidateSheet is called from ThisWorkBook in a Workbook_Open sub.
I had asked this question before but alot of people asked me to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example. I am fairly new to both stackoverflow and vba. Thanks in advance

like this:

```
sheet8.ValidateSheet
```

this is my ValidateSheet

```
Public Sub ValidateSheet()

   allowEdit

   ValidationTools.validateDropDown Sheet8, cbApplication, CB_APPLICATION_ERR_RANGE
   disallowEdit

End Sub
```

this is RedBorder:

```
Public Sub RedBorder(sheet As Worksheet, rangeString As String)

  With Worksheets("sheet").Range(rangeString).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = vbRed
    .Weight = xlThin
  End With

End Sub
```

this is validateDropDown:

```
Public Sub validateDropDown(sheet As Worksheet, ddl As msforms.ComboBox, rangeString As String)
  With sheet
   If ddl.ListIndex = -1 Then
    RedBorder sheet, rangeString
    'add message
    .Range(rangeString).Value = "Please make a selection"

   Else
    NoBorder sheet, rangeString
    'remove message
     .Range(rangeString).Value = ""
  End If
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please go back and delete your old question as this is a better explanation to that one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741654/error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error#45741654

Comment: Or rather, *edit it into shape* - the more poorly-received questions you have on your account, the more likely the system blocks you from asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sheet` is already a `Worksheet` object, so you dont put it in quotes or use the `Worksheets()` part either.

```
Public Sub RedBorder(sheet As Worksheet, rangeString As String)

  With sheet.Range(rangeString).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = vbRed
    .Weight = xlThin
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted and deleted mine. I couldve adjusted had i seen this earlier - works been crazy